# Xamarin.Forms; Getting a tabbed page to be inside a MasterDetail Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a master detail page with a burger icon at the top that shows the drawer menu. But the master detail itself is only one page, id like it to be 2 pages ( like in the tabbed page, where u can swipe between the two).

I have tried the following:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <TabbedPage>
        <TabbedPage.Children>
            <ContentPage Title="Page 1" Icon="ja.png" />
            <ContentPage Title="Page 2" Icon="ja.png" />
            <ContentPage Title="Page 3" Icon="ja.png" />
        </TabbedPage.Children>
    </TabbedPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

This does display mulitple pages inside the master detail, but it also removes the burger and the whole navigation bar also.

Is there a way to enable a tabbed page inside a master detail and still have the navigation bar with the burger icon?

Thank you!

Comment: In your case it would be better to use Shell . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction

Answer (score 0):

I only works when you have another page that is a tabbed page and render it here:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Q2go.View.MasterDetailPage1"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Q2go.View">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MasterDetailPage1Master x:Name="MasterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:TabbedPage1/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `TabbedPage` in a `NavigationPage` as such:

```
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <TabbedPage>
                <TabbedPage.Children>
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 1" Icon="ja.png" />
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 2" Icon="ja.png" />
                    <ContentPage Title="Page 3" Icon="ja.png" />
                </TabbedPage.Children>
            </TabbedPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: That doesnt work. it will remove the navigation bar for some reason. See my answer, it is szuper easy. thank you

Comment: @user13397492 Is this not what you want to achieve? https://imgur.com/a/Aa5U5f5

Comment: No, the burger icon and the whole navigation bar MUST remain! I did it yself (see answer below)